# Set header in Apache .htaccess if URI contains a word

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

I want to set a custom header in `.htaccess` if the URI contains the word `/account`, e.g. it should match the following URIs `http://www.example.com/account`, `http://www.example.com/account/address`.

I tried with the following code but it is not working:

```
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ /account/">
    Header set Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
</If>
```

However, when I remove the if statement, the header is being set correctly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may use `THE_REQUEST` in `If` condition to avoid this block getting modified `REQUEST_URI`:

```
<If "%{THE_REQUEST} =~ m#\s/+account[/?\s]#">
    Header set Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
</If>
```

Comment: sorry to comment an old question, but your solution worked for me either. You know why it works with THE_REQUEST but it does not work with REQUEST_URI?

Comment: I wrote it in answer also. `REQUEST_URI` changes due to other directives but `THE_REQUEST` doesn't.

Comment: @anubhava  Can you tell me what syntactic scheme you are using to make the comparison on the right-hand side? I would like to understand it, but I don't understand the regex expression and I can't find any documentation.

Comment: It is very basic regex that matches a white space followed by text account followed by a / or ? or a white space